# No such file or directory ... `/venv/bin/python`

Tags: python, macos, amazon-web-services, serverless

I'm in the process of installing Serverless, Python, AWS and more on a new machine and when I try to run a deploy, I get a failure:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/myUser/dev (legacy)/myApp/venv/bin/python'`

When I cd into `myApp/venv/bin/`, I see what look like aliases (or symlinks?) to python and python3 so I'm not entirely sure what's going on here.

I have a virtual environment running when I do my deploy, for what it's worth.

Thanks

Comment: The issue might be "/dev (legacy)/"

Comment: Good catch. I'll try it in my regular `dev` folder